# React Native Stripe API Error (maestro is only available in iOS 12.0 or newer)

Tags: react-native, stripes, xcode14

I face an issue during running react native project on xcode version 14.1.

I get an error 'maestro' is only available in iOS 12.0 or newer. I also update target version but getting no success.

[image]

Delete node_modules, pod files but getting no success.

Comment: Any success on this one, mate?